# Cannot make requests parse a website with login

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information from a internet diary, but it requires login. I watched multiple guides and different posts but somehow I still can't log in into  website.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

url="https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Pamoka/MokinioDienynasList"

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
headers = {
    'headers': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {
    'UserName': '',
    'Password': '',
    'IsMobileUser': 'false',
    'ReturnUrl': '/Pamoka/Sarasas',
    'RequireCaptcha': 'false',
'SToken':''
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Pamoka/Sarasas'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Results from using network tab and finding post is:

```
UserName: Name
Password: Pass
IsMobileUser: false
ReturnUrl: 
RequireCaptcha: false
Timestamp: 2021-03-09 23:29:32
SToken: 589edfbe010dafesdcvc373e025fgfe4863c5sdgvbf945eb80bbf7ca93sdas8 (not real token tho)
```

Comment: How do you obtain `SToken`?

Comment: FYI ‘to scrap’ means to throw away - the correct term is __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get that `SToken` and (just to be sure) `Timestamp`. Other fields you can fill in manually.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session


url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

session = Session()
session.headers = headers

r = session.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features='html.parser')
form = soup.select_one('#main_form')

timestamp = form.select_one('#Timestamp')['value']
stoken = form.select_one('#SToken')['value']

payload = {
    'Username': '<your username>',
    'Password': '<your password>',
    'IsMobileUser': False,
    'ReturnUrl': '/Pamoka/MokinioDienynasList',
    'RequireCaptcha': False,
    'Timestamp': timestamp,
    'SToken': stoken
}

r = session.post(url, json=payload)
r.raise_for_status()
```

I can't check if this works as expected because I can't register on this site to check it out, but when I ran this and check for error code the output was:

```py
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> print(soup.select_one('.error').text)
Neteisingas prisijungimo vardas ir/arba slaptažodis
```

Which, I believe, translates to *Invalid login name and/or password*. But when I substitute `stoken` to some random value, no error message was in response.

You can check this code out and see if it works for you.